# React Facebook API suddently throwing error

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a live React app that I use to control OBS and stream to Facebook. It has been in production for almost half a year now but suddenly is throwing the following error in the console when trying to access a long-lived access token:

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified invariant #47458; %s Params: %s`

My code to access this has not changed

```
        window.FB.api(`/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_FB_APP_ID}&client_secret=${process.env.REACT_APP_FB_APP_SECRET}&fb_exchange_token=${res.authResponse.accessToken}`
        , (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          window.FB.api(`/${userId}/accounts?access_token=${res.access_token}`, (res) => {
            ...
        }, (err) => console.log(err))
```

The error happens on the api call. I added the error handling after to try and catch it but it doesn't even get there. Any guidance would be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run the app locally and report the non-minified error?

Comment: Yes. I get the exact same error locally and on production.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/620565116029656/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error at the same time in JavaScript. Now it's gone again.

Comment: That is strange. Must be an issue with their end. Works for me too! Thanks a lot.